# How can I get verbatim href attribute

Tags: html, ruby, rspec, capybara, internal-link

I have a page-internal link in an html page:

```
<div class="bar">
  <a href="#foo">Go to foo</a>
</div>
```

I selected this anchor element using Capybara matcher. When I try to access the `href` attribute, the value is expanded to full URL:

```
find(".bar a")[:href] # => "http://path/to/page#foo"
```

How can get only the internal link, i.e., the verbatim href value?

```
find(".bar a")... # => "#foo"
```

Comment: Can't replicate this with capybara 2.4.3 and rspec 3.5.0. `find('.bar a')[:href]
#=> "#foo"`

Comment: @omnikron That is sort of surprising. I am using capybara 2.12.0 and rspec 3.5.0.

Comment: I don't suppose you're using any kind of path helper to generate the anchor tag...? Worth double-checking the html in that case maybe. Otherwise I am stumped.

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: @omnikron 2.4.3 is massively out of date

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @ThomasWalpole. Is an upgrade going to be easy and make my tests faster?

Comment: @omnikron 2.4.3 is over 2 years old, so while theoretically it should be an easy upgrade (semver, etc) a lot has been added.  Not sure it will make your tests faster but it will make some types of expectations/behaviors cleaner to write and fixes a bunch of issues/differences between drivers, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capybara returns the property `href` (as opposed to the attribute) in JS capable drivers, which is normalized.  To get access to the attribute value you will need to use evaluate_script

```
link = find(".bar a")
evaluate_script("arguments[0].getAttribute('href')", link)
```

If, on the other hand, you just want to verify the link has that specific href attribute you can do that with the :link selector

```
expect(page).to have_link('Go to foo', href: '#foo')
```

or to find the link by the href attribute

```
link = find(:link, href: '#foo')
```

etc...